# How can I set the timePattern in a dijit.form.TimeTextBox to show hours:minutes am|pm

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have this dojo TimeTextBox in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="startTime" value="" dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox"></input>
```

and this JS code:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(
   function(){    
      var sartTime = dijit.byId('startTime');
   }
)
```

So how do I format the time to look like HH:mm am|pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constraints.timePattern attribute:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="startTime" 
       value="" 
       dojoType="dijit.form.TimeTextBox" 
       constraints="{timePattern:'h:mm a'}" />
```

You'll still get a Date object when you ask the TimeTextBox for its value though. To actually get a string on the format `HH:mm am|pm|` you have to convert it manually afterwards.